# Failed to restore NuGet package Access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I started working on one project that was not written by me, he was on bitbucket, pulled it to his computer and I can not restore the packages nugget gives an error.

```
Failed to restore NuGet package for **** project: Access denied on path "... \ packages \ Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.ru.5.2.7 \ .signature.p7s"
```

and there are 20 such errors for each of the NuGet packages the error is with signature.p7s.

I found the answer that you need to reinstall packages, but when uninstalling, the same error occurs and visual studio does not allow you to remove them.

Comment: have you tried remove and install the nuget that is included?

Comment: packages NuGet? 
or just NuGet? if NuGet just did not do it, tell me how to do it?

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling nuget package manager, but it didn't help

Comment: On another computer, there was no such problem, I will figure out what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling Visual studio on this pc helped me

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio needs administration access to R/W files.
As your error says "Access denied" Visual Studio doesn't have admin permission.

Try to open with Administrator. Right click ok VS and "Run as administrator".

Comment: this was checked in the first place, I also have a domain account, on another PC with the same account everything works